# Calling a method that is unspecified at compile time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Tinkering in Unity, I have a part of my GUI that will render information (e.g. enemy stats) from one of several different class types representing different things in the game. All of the different classes have a method for creating an information object that contains the desired information (e.g. enemyInfoObject), which have a DrawInfo() method that draws the info depending on the gameObject.

In my information-rendering script I would like to be able to assign any one of the different information objects to a single variable (i.e. the currently selected enemy, NPC, etc.) and be able to call the DrawInfo() method. Is there a clean, simple, and/or better way to do this?

I can elaborate if needed.

Comment: Use interface? (`interface {void DrawInfo();}`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a well-known design pattern called the ["Strategy Pattern"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). It extends the idea of "programming to an interface".

> The strategy pattern is intended to provide a means to define a family
>   of algorithms, encapsulate each one as an object, and make them
>   interchangeable. The strategy pattern lets the algorithms vary
>   independently from clients that use them.

First, define an interface containing `DrawInfo`,say `ISprite`. All your sprites will be classes that implement this interface. Now the game can store a reference to the selected `ISprite` and call the method on it.

For example:

```
public interface ISprite
{
    void Draw();
}

public class BossMonster : ISprite
{
    public override void Draw()
    {
        // Draw scary stuff
    }
}

public class NPC : ISprite
{
    public override void Draw()
    {
        // Draw stuff
    }
}

public class Game
{
    private ISprite currentSprite = ...
    private List<ISprite> otherSprites = ...

    public void Render()
    {
        currentSprite.Draw();

        foreach (ISprite sprite in otherSprites)
        {
            sprite.Draw();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - interfaces in C# are new to me. I was going to ask if the interface bit is inheritable from a separate C# script in Unity, but after some testing it appears they are.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I can think of is to make all of the objects in your game that you'd like to call DrawInfo() on implement an interface like `IDrawableInfo`:

#### IDrawableInfo.cs

```
public interface IDrawableInfo
{
    void DrawInfo();
}
```

#### EnemyInfoObject.cs

```
public class EnemyInfoObject : IDrawableInfo
{
    public void DrawInfo()
    {
        // Do drawing stuff here
    }
}
```

#### YourScript.cs

```
if(objectIdLikeToDrawInfoFor is IDrawableInfo)
{
    objectIdLikeToDrawInfoFor.DrawInfo();
}
```

You can avoid runtime errors by wrapping your `DrawInfo()` calls in an if statement like this.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Would that I could set more than one answer as accepted.